# Querying mongoDB using R and creating different dataframes based on the distinct values in a column

Tags: r, rmongodb

I want to have different dataframes created based on the distinct values of a column while querying the MongoDB.

For example- write now i am filtering the whole collection and creating a data frame for one single campaign.

```
query = mongo.bson.buffer.create()
mongo.bson.buffer.append(query,"campaign", "Belt Buckles")
query<-mongo.bson.from.buffer(query)
cursor = mongo.find(mongo, ns=DBNS, query= query)
```

But i have seven different campaigns and the query should be able to identify the distinct campaigns by itself and create different dataframes from MongoDB

How should give that "distinct" in my query?

Sample data--

Here is a sample data-

```
IS  LISR  LISB    campaign
90   5    5        Belts 
95  2.5   2.5      Books 
80  10    10       Books 
70  15    15       Bags 
75  12    13       Bags 
65  15    20       Belts
```

I want belts, books, bags into different dataframes

Comment: you can query each "campaign" in a loop. Or you can split your "messy" data.frame by unique campaign.
PS seems you overall data manipulation pipeline is not optimal
PS2 don't use mongo.bson.buffer - use mongo.bson.from.list instead

Comment: thank you Dmitriy for response.. but as of now there are 7 campaigns, but my concern is what if there are 100 campaigns. do i need to write all campaign names in the list.. what i was looking for is query should automatically identify the distinct campaigns and pass it to the list by itself!

The reason why i want to do this, this is a huge collection and i dont want to take the whole collection into a dataframe and do the disticnt over there as this process is going to be automated, there is a time concern!